# How to generate functional code coverage file in golang of a repo

Tags: go, automation, code-coverage

I am using this command.

```
    go test -o=bin/application -c -covermode=count -coverpkg ./...
```

I tried the above command and didnt got the output file at the location.

Comment: What you want is `-coverprofile`, not `-o`. To get a list of flags supported by `go test`, run `go help testflag`.

Answer (score 0):

`go test -o` is creating a test binary. From `go help test`:

```
        -o file
            Compile the test binary to the named file.
            The test still runs (unless -c or -i is specified).
```

You want to generate a coverage profile then use the [cover](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/cover) tool to analyze it. From `go help testflag`:

```
         -coverprofile cover.out
            Write a coverage profile to the file after all tests have passed.
            Sets -cover.
```

I believe what you want is something like this:

```bash
# Output to bin/coverage.out
go test -coverprofile=bin/coverage.out -covermode=count
# Generate coverage as html
go tool cover -html=bin/coverage.out -o bin/coverage.html
```

Then inspect `bin/coverage.html`.